# How to prepare videos for Restream.io Scheduler streams with ffmpeg

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg, streaming

Following [this official restream.io guide](https://support.restream.io/en/articles/2055493-how-to-prepare-videos-for-scheduler-streams-with-handbrake), I would like a person with some ffmpeg experience to translate this page into an `ffmpeg command` in order to save us, linux users, from having to install HandBrake just for video transcoding (I believe *transcoding* is the word that this guide wants us to do).

**UPDATE:**
The desired video output seems to be (please, compare and give me some feedback for correctness):

- MP4 (?)
- 720p
- 30 FPS
- Web Optimized - Optimize MP4 for progressive download. After encoding, data is reorganized and rewritten, to allow immediate playback over a network, without needing to download the entire file
- 1280x720 or 960x540
- Video codec: H.264 (x264)
- Constant framerate
- bitrate: 4000 kbit/s or 800 kbit/s
- encoder preset: medium or veryfast
- keyframe interval: every 2 seconds ==> 60 or keyint=60 (not sure if keyint helps clarify some doubts)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ffmpeg -i <input_path> -c:v libx264 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) <output_path>
```

I'm not sure if this will meet your needs exactly, but then again I am not an `ffmpeg` expert, just an occasional user.

Comment: what does `expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)` mean? Thank you for responding @VicerExciser

Comment: Sorry, that is the value for the `-force_key_frames` option that will force a key frame every 5 seconds. If you want every two seconds, it should actually be `expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)`. More details can be found here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html